# Pytorch autograd: Make gradient of a parameter a function of another parameter

Tags: pytorch, autograd

In Pytorch, how can I make the gradient of a parameter a function itself?

Here is a simple code snippet:

```
import torch

def fun(q):

    def result(w):
        l = w * q
        l.backward()
        return w.grad

    return result

w = torch.tensor((2.), requires_grad=True)
q = torch.tensor((3.), requires_grad=True)

f = fun(q)

print(f(w))
```

In the code above, how can I make f(w) have gradient with respect to q?

EDIT: based on the accepted answer I was able to write a code that works. Essentially I am alternating between 2 optimization steps. For dim == 1 it works and for dim == 2 it does not. I get the error "RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the saved intermediate results have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time."

```
import torch 

class f_class():
    def __init__(self, dim):    
        self.dim = dim
        if self.dim == 1:      
            self.w = torch.tensor((3.), requires_grad=True)
        elif self.dim == 2:            
            self.w = [torch.tensor((3.), requires_grad=True), torch.tensor((5.), requires_grad=True)]
        else:
            raise ValueError("dim 1 or 2")
        
    def forward(self, x):
        if self.dim == 1:      
            return torch.mul(self.w, x)
        elif self.dim == 2:  
            return torch.mul(torch.mul(self.w[0], self.w[1]), x)            
           
    def set_w(self, w):
        self.w = w
        
    def get_w(self):
        return self.w
    
class g_class():
    def __init__(self):                
        self.q = torch.tensor((4.), requires_grad=True)
        
    def forward(self, f):
        return torch.mul(self.q, f)
    
    def set_q(self, q):
        self.q = q
        
    def get_q(self):
        return self.q
        
def w_new(f, g, dim):  
    
    loss_g = g.forward(f.forward(xd))
    
    if dim == 1:
        grads = torch.autograd.grad(loss_g, f.get_w(), create_graph=True, only_inputs=True)[0]
           
        temp = f.get_w().detach() + grads        
    else:                
        grads = torch.autograd.grad(loss_g, f.get_w(), create_graph=True, only_inputs=True)
        
        temp = [wi.detach() + gi for wi, gi in zip(f.get_w(), grads)] 

    return temp    

def q_new(f, g):          

    loss_f = 2 * f.forward(xd) 
       
    loss_f.backward()

    temp = g.get_q().detach() + g.get_q().grad
    
    temp.requires_grad = True
    
    return temp

dim = 1

xd = torch.tensor((2.))
        
f = f_class(dim)
g = g_class()

for _ in range(3):
    
    print(f.get_w(), g.get_q())
    
    wnew = w_new(f, g, dim)
    
    f.set_w(wnew)
    print(f.get_w(), g.get_q())

    qnew = q_new(f, g)
    
    g.set_q(qnew)
    
print(f.get_w(), g.get_q())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When computing gradients, if you want to construct a computation graph for the gradient itself you need to specify `create_graph=True` to autograd.

A potential source of error in your code is using `Tensor.backward` within `f`. The problem here is that `w.grad` and `q.grad` will be populated with the gradient of `l`. This means that when you call `f(w).backward()`, the gradients of both `f` and `l` will be added to `w.grad` and `q.grad`. In effect you will end up with `w.grad` being equal to `dl/dw + df/dw` and similarly for `q.grad`. One way to get around this is to zero the gradients after `f(w)` but before `.backward()`. A better way is to use `torch.autograd.grad` within `f`. Using the latter approach, the `grad` attribute of `w` and `q` will not be populated when calling `f`, only when calling `.backward()`. This leaves room for things like gradient accumulation during training.

```py
import torch

def fun(q):
    def result(w):
        l = w * q 
        return torch.autograd.grad(l, w, only_inputs=True, retain_graph=True)[0]
    return result


w = torch.tensor((2.), requires_grad=True)
q = torch.tensor((3.), requires_grad=True)

f = fun(q)

f(w).backward()

print('w.grad:', w.grad)
print('q.grad:', q.grad)
```

which results in

```
w.grad: None
q.grad: tensor(1.)
```

Note that `w.grad` was not populated. This is because `f(w) = dl/dw = q` is not a function of `w`, and therefore `w` is not part of the computation graph. If you're using a standard pytorch optimizer this is fine since `None` gradients are implicitly assumed to be zero.

If `l` were instead a non-linear function of `w`, then `w.grad` would have been populated after `f(w).backward()`. For example

```py
import torch

def fun(q):
    def result(w):
        # now dl/dw = 2 * w * q
        l = w**2 * q
        return torch.autograd.grad(l, w, only_inputs=True, create_graph=True)[0]
    return result

w = torch.tensor((2.), requires_grad=True)
q = torch.tensor((3.), requires_grad=True)

f = fun(q)

f(w).backward()

print('w.grad:', w.grad)
print('q.grad:', q.grad)
```

which results in

```
w.grad: tensor(6.)
q.grad: tensor(4.)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for one dimensional w but for a two dimensional one I get the error "RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the saved intermediate results have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time."

Could you please check my edit above? The code is really straightforward.